# how to get values basis on keys from a Struct Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this value as

```
%{is_public: true, discoverable: true}
```

This could be anything not specifically `is_public` and `discoverable`, but all the `keys` which will come in above `Map` will be available in a `struct` of a camera.

```
%Camera{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "cameras">,
  created_at: #DateTime<2017-08-25 14:13:55.524563Z>,
  discoverable: true,
  exid: "everc-fhlcr",
  id: 12769,
  is_online: true,
  is_online_email_owner_notification: false,
  is_public: true,
  last_online_at: #DateTime<2019-05-14 11:10:45.000000Z>,
  last_polled_at: #DateTime<2019-05-14 11:10:47.000000Z>,
}
```

I want to get the values from the `Camera` struct on the basis of `Map` i.e

```
iex(4)> changes = %{is_public: true, discoverable: true} |> Map.keys
[:discoverable, :is_public]
```

I can get the keys from changes map with `Map.keys`

But I am not sure about how to map values from Camera struct.

from above Camera Struct and changes map, I want to get this type of Map.

```
%{
 is_public: true,
 discoverable: true
}
```

it seems like the same above map but it depends on Camera Struct values, they both can be false or true , same as id, exid, is_online.

If I do this

```
Enum.map(changed_keys, fn(key) ->
  key: Map.get(camera, key)
end)
```

This still doesn't work, any help would be appreciable. thanks

I just want to make a map with anonymous keys in `changes` Map, and then get their values from `Camera` Struct and create a new map with those values and anonymouse keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first task is to extract needed keys - it's already done perfectly with:

```
Map.keys(my_map)
```

Passing `%{is_public: true, discoverable: true}` as `my_map` make the deal:

```
iex> Map.keys(%{is_public: true, discoverable: true})
[:is_public, :discoverable]
```

Now, the question is - how to build one map from another, which will have **only** specified keys.

Fortunately, we have such a function in standard library: [Map.take](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#take/2)

We can use it like this:

```
Map.take(camera, [:discoverable, :is_public])
```

or (in particular case)

```
Map.take(camera, changes)
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I’d post the solution that uses [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension. Here it’s probably an ovekill, but in general it gives way more flexibility on filtering and any further processsing:

```rb
for {k, v} <- camera, k in [:discoverable, :is_public],
  do: {k, v}, into: %{}
#⇒ %{discoverable: true, is_public: true}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `into` option. Cool!

Comment: @OleksiiFilonenko also [`reduce:`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-the-reduce-option) starting with released today `1.9`.

Comment: I was waiting for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of [`Map.keys/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#keys/1) and [`Map.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#take/2).

```
changes = Map.keys(%{is_public: true, discoverable: true})  # [:is_public, :discoverable]

Map.take(camera, changes)  # %{is_public: true, discoverable: true}
```